# Rails migration to clear contents of a database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

The (occasionally very large) output of some JSON-calls get written into my database to speed things up a little; the app gets the JSON-output pre-rendered from the database.

Every once there's a little change in the content so the output would have been different. I'm looking for a rails migration that I could just include in my deployment for clearing out the specific table storing my JSON code.

Comment: So basically you are implementing a caching mechanism on your own. Why  don't you use rails caching, as described here? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Post.delete_all # => delete all records in posts table

Answer (score 0):

You can put that in your migration. Warning, this will delete all data from the table !

```
Model.connection.execute('DELETE FROM table_name');
```

Or altenatively you could run some code every day (crontab) to delete everything that is X months old :

```
def self.delete_old_stuff
  month = 3
  Model.where("updated_at < ?" , month.months.ago).each{|c| c.destroy}
end
```

You can call that through the runner command of rails or integrate that a in rake task... I use a similar method to clear old basket in a small ecommerce app.

Comment: It's 'DELETE FROM table_name' (no *)

Comment: This might be brain freeze on my part, but "Model" not found. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Ok I worked it out. In a migration, its just execute(sql) , without the Model.connection